# this query fetches repeatidly records. please tell me query which only fetch record on according to ON

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query fetches same records repeatedly . Please tell me query which fetches only records according to `ON` or `WHERE`

```
SELECT reward_sender.reward_no,reward_sender.reward_id,reward_sender.sender_id 
FROM reward_sender 
INNER JOIN rewards1 
   ON reward_sender.reward_no=1 
  AND reward_sender.sender_id=1 
  AND reward_sender.reward_id=1
```

Thanks..

Comment: I suspect you probably need to include amongst your join criteria some expression of the relationship between the records in your two tables.

Comment: You don't seem to have a WHERE in there.

Comment: please tell me how to do this.

Comment: @user1824546 - do what? It's not at all clear from your question what result you're trying to get.

Comment: @user1824546: a join usually has a condition of the type: `ON reward_sender.SomeColumn = rewards1.SomeOtherColumn` (and often these two columns have the same name)

Comment: first i have used where but i do not need column of second table (rewards1) thats why i have used inner Join

Comment: if you do not need the table rewards1 why do you use in the query? if want to talk to your girlfriend, did you take your mother with you?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the JOIN at all. The second table is nowhere to be used, neither inside SELECT nor for any comparison. Leave it out, and you'll be fine.